# Python, Zeep response to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, zeep

I am tryng to conenct to a SOAP webservice and use pandas to put in on a table.

Zeep give me this list:

```
[{
    'ssPeca': '103',
    'ssQtd': '1',
    'ssUn': 'un'
}, {
    'ssPeca': '291A',
    'ssQtd': '8',
    'ssUn': 'un'
}, {
    'ssPeca': '406B',
    'ssQtd': '8',
    'ssUn': 'un'
}]
```

my code is this:

```
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
pecas=client.service.TabelaPecas("C-160","CR")

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pecas)
```

and that code generate this:

```
      0     1    2
0  ssPeca ssQtd ssUn 
1  ssPeca ssQtd ssUn 
2  ssPeca ssQtd ssUn
```

but i want this:

```
      0     1    2
0    103    1   un 
1    291A   8   un 
2    406B   8   un
```

can anyone help? i am just a beginner in python.

Comment: What's the type of `pecas`? If it were a dict, you would get the desired output. Try `pd.DataFrame.from_records(pecas)` maybe? Or try `pecas = dict(pecas)` first.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(pecas)` should do the job

Comment: Hi @Orenshi , pd.DataFrame(pecas) gives the same result.

Comment: Hi @ayhan, pecas is a List. pd.DataFrame.from_records(pecas) does not Work.

pecas = dict(pecas) gives me this error: "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required"

Comment: I deleted my answer since I'm not quite understanding what `pecas` contains. Does `pecas` equal the list you first mentioned in the post?

Comment: @Orenshi, I did a connection to a soap webservice and it give me that response in a form of a list that i put in the main post.

When i do a print(pecas) i get that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this:

```
from zeep import Client
import pandas as pd

labels = ['Peça', 'Qtd']
desenho="C-160"
montagem="CR"

client = Client('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
resposta=list(client.service.TabelaPecas(desenho,montagem))

pecas=[]
for record in resposta:
    peca = record.ssPeca
    qtd  = record.ssQtd
    pecas.append([peca,qtd])


print('Desenho', desenho ,' Montagem', montagem)
pd.DataFrame(data=pecas,columns=labels )
```

Probably it is because i am a beginner in python and probably this is a workaround but works with the zeep response. Using pd.DataFrame with a list works but not with zeep response.

Maybe some day will help a beginner like me.

Answer (score 14):

Zeep has a function to transform the response into python objects. Eg: Ordered Dict.

You should use:

```
from zeep.helpers import serialize_object

client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
pecas=client.service.TabelaPecas("C-160","CR")

pecas = serialize_object(pecas)

pd.DataFrame(pecas)
```

source: http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/helpers.ht

edit: Fixed typo, thanks voglster

Comment: from zip.helpers import serialize_object should be from zeep.helpers import serialize_object

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data (list of dicts) directly to the pd.DataFrame. And it should look the way you want it.

```
>>> data = [{
...     'ssPeca': '103',
...     'ssQtd': '1',
...     'ssUn': 'un'
... }, {
...     'ssPeca': '291A',
...     'ssQtd': '8',
...     'ssUn': 'un'
... }, {
...     'ssPeca': '406B',
...     'ssQtd': '8',
...     'ssUn': 'un'
... }]
>>> pd.DataFrame(data=data)
  ssPeca ssQtd ssUn
0    103     1   un
1   291A     8   un
2   406B     8   un
```

Comment: Does no work with pd.DataFrame(data=pecas). it gives me the same result.

Comment: Hi,

Your example works but with the list that i get from zeep it does not.