# SOAP API to fetch Workday data in Python in JSON response?

Tags: python, api, soap, workday-api

Can anyone please share how you can receive as JSON\XML response
when using  Workday SOAP API ? I tried using workday library and gets an object of type zeep which I am unable to parse to a dataframe.

from workday.auth import WsSecurityCredentialAuthentication

zeep.objects.Cost_Center_Response_DataType.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the answers covered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528268/python-zeep-response-to-pandas

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Get_Worker api operation, use below code.

assume you get response from workday in `result` variable

```
for worker in result.Response_Data.Worker:
  if worker.Worker_Data is not None:
    print(worker.Worker_Data.Worker_ID)
```

the above code will print worker id. I same way you an get other attributes as well